# only returning 10 values with no LIMIT set?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, date, eloquent

i have done a function where a user will select a "from" and "to" date and it will return the values of the date selected by user and and it will count the different users on that day and it will also group the same date then count. so it will return something like which is correct
[image]

but the problem i'm facing now is that it will only return max 10 value and not more. so if i select 1/3/2018 - 15/3/2018 it only returns from 1/3/2018 to 10/3/2018. why is this happening?

my code as below:

```html
public function viewUniqueVisitorByDate(Request $request, $companyID)
{
$companyID = $this->decode($companyID);

$allUsers = DiraChatLog::whereBetween('date_access', [$request->from, $request->to])->orderBy('date_access', 'asc')->get();
foreach ($allUsers as $key => $users) {
  $dates = strtotime($users->date_access); 
  $newformat = date('Y-m-d',$dates);
  $userDates[$newformat] = $this->getUsers($newformat,$users);
}

dd($userDates);

$user = array_values($userDates);
$dates = array_keys($userDates);
// dd($user, $dates);

$from = $request->from;
$to = $request->to;
// dd($from, $to);

$companyID = $this->encodeID($companyID);

return view('AltHr.Chatbot.viewUniqueVisitor', compact('companyID','from','to', 'dates'))->with('user',json_encode($user,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK))->with('dates',json_encode($dates,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));     
}
```

```html
private function getUsers($date,$users)
{
$userDates = Carbon::parse($date)->addDay()->toDateTimeString();
// dd($userDates,$date);

$noOfUsers = DiraChatLog::whereBetween('date_access', [$date,$userDates])->get();
// dd($noOfUsers);

return $noOfUsers->groupBy('user_id')->count();
}
```

database table structure
[image]

Comment: So you expect it to return 15 but got 10 records? Am I getting your question here?

Comment: @Wils yes you are right!

Comment: @JohnDoe date format in db and can you hit the same query again in db are you getting 15 records

Comment: can you show us your tables structure ?

Comment: @saurabhkamble what do you mean? but when i dd($from,$to); i get the right dates

Comment: @grappler added table straucture

Comment: $request->from and $request->to are datetime format ?

Answer (score 1):

if `$request->from` and `$request->to` are not a datetime format. In every where clauses, should be.

```
DiraChatLog::whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(date_access)'), [$request->from, $request->to])
            ->orderBy('date_access', 'asc')->get();

$noOfUsers = DiraChatLog::whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(date_access)'), [$date,$userDates])->get();
```

because `date_access` is a datetime format.
**Do not forget to declare use DB;**